# Accessing a virtual hard drive like it's a physical drive from the real machine

Tags: windows, virtual-machine

I'm trying to do changes to drive C on my Windows virtual machine using my real machine. Shared folders is not what I need because I want to access the VM's folders such as `C:\Windows` or `C:\Program Files` and not to add a hard drive.

Can someone please help me? Thanks.

edit: I want to also be able to write in the folders and not just open it as read-only.

Comment: What's the format of the virtual disk file?

Comment: .vhdx files can be mounted directly in windows. Other formats may require tools before you can access them. .vdi files can be opened directly with 7-zip.

Comment: Thanks guys I was able to access it using 7-zip.

Comment: Can you mark it as answered then? That way others will know you no longer need help.

Comment: Actually I noticed that using 7-zip it's read-only. I want to also be able to change the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to best answer the question, we need to know what extension the virtual disk has.

That said...

.vhd and .vhdx files can be mounted directly in windows.

Other formats may require tools before you can access them.

.vdi files can be opened directly with 7-zip.

If the virtual disk is a windows dynamic disk, you can't open them up in external tools to get data from them because a dynamic disk will have 3 files on them. One is the .img file that contains all data, one is a database and I forgot what the 3rd file was. In that case, you need to create a virtual machine with a windows install, add that harddisk to its settings, boot up the virtual machine and access the files that way.

See here:
[image]

Comment: so can the older VHDs.

Comment: Right. Added it. Thanks @JourneymanGeek :)

Comment: The .img file + database thing sounds like another of 7-zip inventions...

Comment: @user1686 no its not. It is what a Dynamic disk becomes. If you create a .vdi file and mount it normally, then create files/folders, the .vdi can be opened with 7-zip and you see the files/folders normally. If you then turn it into a dynamic disk, and you open it then, you only see 3 files. I've attached a screenshot so you can see what I mean. The filesystem in this screenshot has only 1 partition, it spans 2 drives (aka 2 .vdi files)

Comment: @LPChip: Well, yes, but 7-zip does this sort of thing for many other file formats (e.g. opening an .exe will show its sections as files even though they aren't anything like files). That doesn't mean it's an actual filesystem that has an .img file in it. Looking at how Linux handles LDM, it seems to be much more like a partition table type.

Comment: @user1686 oh, I see... Yeah, that could be the case. My point in the answer was more to indicate that if this is the case, you can't just copy the files from the vdi.

Answer (score 0):

To attach a virtual disk as to the host, which is indistinguishable from
a physical disk, do the following:

- Open Disk Management
- Select the menu *Action > Attach VHD*
- Specify the location of the virtual disk, using a fully-qualified path.

This works for virtual disk files with the VHD or VHDX file extension.